# Sockets Receiving Others

Tags: python, sockets, select

I am trying to write python sockets in which there is a server connecting to multiple clients. Server first send files/information to each client independently, and then the clients will do their own processes, after they are done, they would send log file back to server.

For example, server A is connected to X, Y, Z.  A sends "123" to X, "456" to Y, "789" to Z. X, Y Z receive their respective message then each runs its own function. When X finishes, it sends log back to A, at the same time Y may also finish its function and then begins sending back log.

So server has to be first socket.send() then wait for clients. I am using select to handle multiple connections.

My code looks like this

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
while True:
  ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)
  for sock in ready_to_read:
     #a new connection request recieved
     if sock == server_socket:
        sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
        SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
     ...

     #client ready
     else:
         ack_log = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
         recv_log(sock, ack_log)
```

Python 2.6

The problem now is, when server recevies from a socket (lets say this socket is connected to X and have sockd_id of 'A10'), and message sent by X is `this is from x`, but the server actually receives this is from `this is from xTHIS IS FROM Y`.

As you could imagine, client Y at that time is also ready to send log and it sends "THIS IS FROM Y" to its socket (lets give this a sockd_id of 'B10').

What I expected is that since sockd_id `A10` is connected to 'X', why would it receive info sent by 'Y'? If 'Y' is also ready to send, how come, on the server, its message is not processed after first iteration of 'for sock in ready_read:' when 'X' and sockd_id `A10` is done.

I hope I stated this as clear as possible.

Comment: I can assure you that the data is coming in on the appropriate socket(s).  Either your clients are not sending the data you think they are sending, or (more likely) your code is not paying enough attention to which data is coming in on which socket.  In your "else" clause, above, how does recv_log use the parameter "sock" that you pass to it?

Comment: yea, you are right exactly.
It turned out I did not take into account that Python Socket recv() has buffers and waits only when certain number of bytes are reached